# JavaFX Dynamic Code

Tags: java, javafx, dynamic

**I want to immediately after increasing the value of i appear in the label**
Example:

-in i=0 show 0

-in i=1 show 01

-in i=2 show 012

Can You Help me

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane=new Pane();
        Label label=new Label();
        Button bt=new Button("Start");

        pane.getChildren().addAll(bt,label);

        bt.setOnAction(e->{
            for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++) label.setText(label.getText()+i);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,1000,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more realistic example? Presumably you are not really trying to update a label with all integers from 0 to 10,000,000 in a busy loop. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you update the label's value while you are on the user interface's thread. JavaFX works with a model where the updates are done at each 'tick' (60 fps). All the updates done are only visible once your eventhander's code has finished.

Additionally, given that this is a long running task it will result in an unresponsive user interface.

You should use a `Worker` to do the long running task. See the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) on asynchronous processing. Note that it will not guarantee that you will see *all* values as the worker can be quicker than the user interface updates and the system will coalesce these updates.

Comment: Usually the thread is called *JavaFX application thread*. Furthermore `Worker` is an interface. The concrete class that would be helpful here is `Task` or maybe `Timeline` to schedule the updates in specific intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timeline` to accomplish this task.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication177 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        AtomicLong i = new AtomicLong();

        Label label = new Label();
        Button btn = new Button();

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.5), (ActionEvent event) -> {//This controls how fast this should run. This example happens every half of a second
            label.setText(label.getText() + Long.toString(i.getAndIncrement()));
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(10000000);//This controls the amount of time this should run
        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> {//This tells what to do once cycle count is reached
            btn.setDisable(false);
        });

        btn.setText("Start");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            btn.setDisable(true);
            timeline.play();
        });

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(label);
        VBox root = new VBox(stackPane, new StackPane(btn));
        VBox.setVgrow(stackPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I want with a loop if possible (add number is only example)

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test5 extends Application {
    private String text = "";
    private int i;
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Label lblText = new Label("");
        pane.getChildren().add(lblText);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (i=0;i<10000;i++) {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { // Run from JavaFX GUI
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                lblText.setText(lblText.getText()+i);
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
            }
        }).start();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 50);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FlashText"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    //Your First Task #1
                    //Here UI won't be interrupted
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Your Second Task After Completion Of First One #2
                        }
                    });
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    service.start();
}
```

#1. The task that you want to perform in the background ex. loading the data has to be placed here. It's working great for me.

#2. Once the background task is finished this thread will be executed so Ui and background thread will run separately and smoothly.

I know it's too late for this answer but I just wanted to share what I did this might help!